# update in one query multiple rows in a tables with coincidences on postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I update in ONE query a table like this: `WHERE 'featureid' = n AND 'accountid' = n SET ivalue = x OR SET bvalue = y`. Is this possible in postgres?

```
 id  |updatedat           |featureid  |accountid  |bvalue        |ivalue        |
 334 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |1          |90         |              |0             |
 335 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |2          |90         |              |0             |
 337 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |4          |90         |              |0             |
 339 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |6          |90         |              |10            |
 340 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |7          |90         |true          |              |
 341 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |8          |90         |true          |              |
 342 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |9          |90         |false         |              |
```

lets say, i want to have a finish result like:

```
 id  |updatedat           |featureid  |accountid  |bvalue        |ivalue        |
 334 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |1          |90         |              |100           |
 335 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |2          |90         |              |100           |
 337 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |4          |90         |              |100           |
 339 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |6          |90         |              |100           |
 340 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |7          |90         |false         |              |
 341 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |8          |90         |false         |              |
 342 |2018-03-23 00:06:23 |9          |90         |false         |              |
```

Comment: `case when ..then..end`?..

Comment: can i go througth multiple rows with this?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, e.g. `'some words'`. Use double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"Odd column name"`.

Comment: In the text of this question you've got an example of an update query in postgres that test NULL values and set fields depending on the condition, with multiple conditions and multiple fields. Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/5548927/2553194

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET ivalue = x ,bvalue = y
WHERE 'featureid' = n AND 'accountid' = n
```

Comment: I think it's not Jay's fault. Your question it's not clear

Comment: @mridt What do you want to achive? Which condition determines if you set ivalue instead of bvalue? If you want to set ivalue when featureid = n and accountid = n then Andrea's answer may be correct.

Comment: @mridt What do you mean with "passing an object with the replacements"? How do you achieve "passing an object" to a simple query? Don't you need an stored procedure, cursors or another DB structure or a programming language?

Comment: @mridt And you are using postgresql or mysql? Please remove the unused tag.

Comment: how about that @RubioRic ?

Comment: @mridt Much better :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET 
CASE WHEN featureid = n AND accountid = n 
        THEN ivalue = x
CASE WHEN featureid != n AND accountid != n 
        THEN bvalue = y
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct condition to set the bvalue, as it's not really clear in the question